# Spherical geometry vs elliptic geometry

Tags: geometry, terminology

Wikipedia says that "spherical geometry" and "elliptic geometry" are both the geometry of the surface of a sphere. It also asserts that these two geometries are *not* the same — but neglects to explain what the actual difference is.

Does anybody know how these two systems are actually different?

Comment: Elliptical is spherical geometry with opposite points "identified." In spherical geometry, the lines (great circles) intersect in two point. In elliptical geometry, the two points are opposite each other, so are representatives of the same point.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is that really the only difference? (A guess a small change in the axioms probably makes a big difference to the consequences...) And if so, care to make that into an answer?

Comment: Gauss curvature is positive in either case, in the spherical case normal curvatures are  everywhere equal. There is no general Law of Sines in elliptic geometry like in spherical.